# postMessage target origin - window.parent.origin vs "*"

Tags: javascript, postmessage

Is `window.parent.postMessage(message, window.parent.origin)` more secure than `window.parent.postMessage(message, '*')`?

We have an iframe component that is loaded by a parent frame. That frame can be from anywhere (our web application is a shared component and can be accessed from any client installation of our main product). So we can't know in advance who loaded us unless we keep some kind of database with allowed origins which we don't.

We are sending a `postMessage()` to our parent frame, and we can't know the target origin in advance, so I put `'*'`. I colleague of mine suggested I use `window.parent.origin` instead, but as far as I understand this has the same effect - `postMessage` will check that the target origin is the same as itself! Not to mention that it fails when cross-domain.

So am I missing something here? Does using `window.parent.origin` confer any greater security than a wildcard?

Comment: Well without you providing a specific origin, I could possibly embed your component in _my_ page, and then my page would be the receiver of whatever you send via postMessage - whether that could leak sensitive data, is for you to determine. (But simply getting the origin from the parent would not solve that issue either, of course.)

Comment: Well talking absolutely, the `window.parent.origin` option would indeed limit yourself to your own domain, so yes it would be safer, but probably not what you want. Can't you set up some API-key system, that the page using your components could post?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The wildcard `"*"` could be dangerous if parent page gets redirected to a malicious site that could receive your message with sensitive data.

In this particular case, the `parent.origin` wouldn't give any security benefits. Ideally, the component's server should be used to detect and the validate the origin of the parent window.

Comment: And how would `parent.origin` be any safer? I mean **that** is the question being asked here.

Comment: In this particular case, the `parent.origin` wouldn't give any security benefits. Ideally, the component's server should be used to detect and the validate the origin of the parent window.

Answer (score 1):

> Is `window.parent.postMessage(message, window.parent.origin)` more secure than `window.parent.postMessage(message, '*')`?

It depends on what the danger is for you. And what do you consider safe use of your app.

Imagine that your iframe is hosted on domain A, and it is called from domain B. If in this case, sending messages from your iframe to the parent is considered dangerous, then yes - `window.parent.postMessage(message, window.parent.origin)` more secure than `window.parent.postMessage(message, '*')`.

Using `window.parent.origin` as `targetOrigin` will not provide any data to the parent that hosted on a domain other than the iframe domain.